# Google Table Script: Copy Range to next free column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm getting started on using script with Google Tables. To start I wanted to write a simple copy script which takes the values from column A and copy's it to the next free column. My problem right now is that the copyTo function doesn't work with numerical values, but the whole use next free column doesn't work with B1 Ranges or sth similar.
My second thought was using a function which converts numerical range to a "normal" range, sth like convertToRange(2,1) which would return B1. But I couldn't find anything similar again.

Can anyone help me out here?

```
function copy () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("A2:A10");
  var destColumn = ss.getLastColumn();

  source.copyTo(destColumn,1)
  source.clear ();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copyTo expects a range-object (which can be obtained with row, column coordinates or with A1-Notation with the **getRange()** method).

Also, it may be better to provide also the name of the sheet you want to work on.

Finally, you will need to increment the "last column" index with 1 to find the first free column. See if this works

```
  function copy () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var source = ss.getRange ("A2:A10");
  var destColumn = ss.getLastColumn();
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange(1, destColumn+1))
  source.clear ();
}
```

Also see:
[getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) and 
[copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)).

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot that was exactly what i needed. Your points with Sheetname and the increment of the last Column are true and i had those already but wrote a simpler function to describe my problem. Didn't know it was that easy to use a range object.